# Can't import mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pip

I've run a series of commands in my terminal prompt yet i can't get PyCharm to recognize the mysql prompt.

Running:
$ pip3  install mysql-connector-python-rf

Collecting mysql-connector-python-rf
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/21/79/2ff01ab7aa08db3a16b70b990c579c1024c6b2a734263cc7513a758867de/mysql-connector-python-rf-2.2.2.tar.gz (11.9MB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 11.9MB 89kB/s
Building wheels for collected packages: mysql-connector-python-rf
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mysql-connector-python-rf ... done
Stored in directory: /home/deuser/.cache/pip/wheels/87/58/fb/d95c84fad7e1bebfed324c13e107ebb08e1997c9226532859a
Successfully built mysql-connector-python-rf
Installing collected packages: mysql-connector-python-rf
Successfully installed mysql-connector-python-rf-2.2.2

So i succesfully install it yet it remains unrecognized in Pycharm

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the library for your project's environment. Open Preferences -> Interpreter -> Select your system or create new virtualenv and install the library here

Comment: 40:392: execution error: WARNING: The directory '/Users/robsteiner/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

Comment: what do i do now?

Comment: Try to use new virtualenv. It should work without sudo